# Visual Studio intellisense extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, mef

I'm using Visual Studio 2022. I'm trying to write my own language extension that does auto complete for a custom language my work uses.  I have tried following documentation, videos and chat gpt but cannot get the auto complete to work or for that matter even load the symbols on my code.  I have created a class to define an extension and content type

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities;

namespace OpcenterCoreLanguagePlugin.Types
{
    public class FileAndContentTypeDefinitions
    {
        [Export]
        [Name("CommonLanguageFunction")]
        [BaseDefinition("text")]
        internal static ContentTypeDefinition CommonLanguageFunctionDefinition;

        [Export]
        [ContentType("CommonLanguageFunction")]
        [FileExtension(".clf")]
        internal static FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition CommonLanguageFunctionTypeDefinition;
    }
}
```

Then I created a source provider using this code:

```
[Export(typeof(ICompletionSourceProvider))]
[ContentType("CommonLanguageFunction")]
[Name("CLFAutoComplete")]
```

and completion handler

```
[Export(typeof(IVsTextViewCreationListener))]
[Name("CLFcompletionhandler")]
[ContentType("CommonLanguageFunction")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Editable)]
```

My problem is that the symbols don't even seem to load for the actual code of these classes.  I have no included the code because I don't think it is necessarily relevant. I'm just trying to get a static list of strings to display before i start writing the actual logic.

Are there additional steps I am missing? I can't seem to find anything else I'm supposed to do.

I have implemented the following interfaces in my project:

```
IOleCommandTarget
IVsTextViewCreationListener
ICompletionSource 
ICompletionSourceProvider
```

I largely copied the code out of the Visual Studio instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-displaying-statement-completion?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#create-a-mef-project.

Just to see if I could get it working before I strip out their code and replace it with my own.

I was trying to create my own editor for a custom file type of `.clf` and have it auto complete when I type a letter.

Comment: A guess: You probably want the `visual-studio-extensions` tag and not `mef`

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that i had to mark the project as a MEF component in my vsix file for the classes to get read.  took a long time to find that information.

Comment: Hi Chris, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues issue to find the solution easily.